# Combining separate elements into one object in R

Tags: arrays, r, list, object

I have different elements (one of class array and one of class list) that I want to combine into one object that contains both of these elements. Is there a way for me to do this in R?

Array example:

```
>array
, , ind1

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 59.45412 59.41637 60.44459
[2,] 60.53659 60.84746 59.53350
[3,] 60.41962 60.26602 59.15163

, , ind2

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 60.00231 59.23779 59.53094
[2,] 58.68309 58.57091 59.66501
[3,] 60.59827 60.33224 61.53625
```

List example 1:

```
>classifier
ID  habitat
ind1    dry
ind2    wet
```

Desired output:

```
>new_dataset
$array
, , ind1

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 59.45412 59.41637 60.44459
[2,] 60.53659 60.84746 59.53350
[3,] 60.41962 60.26602 59.15163

, , ind2

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 60.00231 59.23779 59.53094
[2,] 58.68309 58.57091 59.66501
[3,] 60.59827 60.33224 61.53625

$habitat
 [1] dry  wet
Levels: dry wet
```

Comment: you mean something like `new_dataset<-list(array=array,habitat=classifier$habitat)`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.